# Call a function of windows application from wcf service function

Tags: c#, wcf

Can I Call a function of windows application from wcf service function,The main purpose of the whole application is: Windows service will detect some event and will show something on windows form application for recognizing the event by the user. Windows service and windows form application should communicate with each other by WCF service.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366317/wcf-accessing-a-windows-forms-controls-from-a-service][1]
this may halp u


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366317/wcf-accessing-a-windows-forms-controls-from-a-service

Comment: I think this a solution only works if your services are hosted inside your windows form application but not on remote location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally web-services are developed to be called by the clients.

To send messages to client, which is the Windows Forms application in your case can be done

1. [Long Polling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlightws/archive/2009/09/30/having-a-pollingduplex-service-and-any-other-wcf-service-in-the-same-website-causes-silverlight-calls-to-be-slow.aspx) or
2. [WCF TCP/IP bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647180.aspx).

Comment: First of all Thanks Asif, Is there any other way to implement like this type of functionality. The main purpose of the whole application is : window application will be installed on multiple system. and admin can send notification message though WCF to all clicent.

Comment: The simplest thing is that call your service periodically in a separate thread and update your windows form application.